# JQmodal pop up can not appear

Tags: php, jquery, popup, jqmodal

I've a problem about jqmodal. That pop up can not appear. My scenario is any data in variable warning, pop up will appear and will appear the all warning data.
This the code. Please help me. Thanks

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo base_url().'css/jqmodal/css/prettify.css'; ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="<? echo base_url().'css/jqmodal/';?>js/prettify.js"> </script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo base_url().'css/jqmodal/';?>css/jquery.modaldialog.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="<? echo base_url().'css/jqmodal/';?>js/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="<? echo base_url().'css/jqmodal/';?>js/jquery.modaldialog.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$().ready(function(){
prettyPrint();
});
</script>
if(@$warning != NULL)
{

             ?>
             <div id="jqModal" class="jqmWindow" style="display: none;"></div>
             <script type="text/javascript">

             jQuery().ready(function($){

             $('#jqModal').jqm({onShow:setText}); 
             $('#jqModal').jqmShow();

             function setText(){
                $('#jqModal').text(<?php echo @$warning;?>);
             }


             });
             </script>
             <?php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Ayu I built a small demo for you **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/BG42j/

Now if you will click on the view... in above demo you will get the text I am setting in my `setText` function. Rest you can play around with the demo. **And please don't forget to accept the answer if this helps. :) Your accept ration is very low :)**

Helpful link:  http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

So I reckon issue was the way setText is declared is not correct /* callback executed when a trigger click. Show notice */ onShow (callback): Called when a dialog is to be shown. Be sure to show (set visible) the dialog.

Hope this helps and have a nice one! cheers

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').jqm({onShow:setText});
   // $('#dialog').jqm().jqmShow({overlay: 70});
});

var setText =  function(h) {
        /* callback executed when a trigger click. Show notice */
        h.w.text('Warning! foooooo');
        h.w.css('opacity',0.92).slideDown(); 
        }
​
```

Comment: can you make a example. ?
if (warning != NULL)
{
your code
}

didn't appear the warning.
what's wrong?

Comment: @Ayu lol Okies, flick me what is warning means (context) and ur condition check seems include might be warning should be compared with empty string man. Anywho let me know about the reference of warning in ur particular case will take a look latter when I am near my laptop and don't forget to accept the answer. Cheers

Comment: ok... i solve my problem no with jqmodal.
but i use jquery... 
http://jqueryui.com

Comment: @Ayu Saweet man did my answer helped you? if yes accept it bruv! :)) have a nice one! cheers.